# Longest route in 2D array from max to min

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, longest-path

There is 2D array `long[50][50]` which is filled with random numbers from 0 to 100. I need to find the longest way from the biggest (or first highest) to the smallest. You can move up, down, left and right.

I found how to find single way: find the biggest nearest number (but no bigger, that it is) and move there.

```
public static int measure = 50;
public long[][] map = new long[measure][measure];
```

My move methods:

```
private long moveUp(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= measure || x == 0 || y == 0 || y >= measure) {
        return -1;
    }
    return map[x - 1][y];
}

private long moveRight(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= measure || x == 0 || y == 0 || y >= measure) {
        return -1;
    }
    return map[x][y + 1];
}

private long moveDown(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= measure || x == 0 || y == 0 || y >= measure) {
        return -1;
    }
    return map[x + 1][y];
}

private long moveLeft(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= measure || x == 0 || y == 0 || y >= measure) {
        return -1;
    }
    return map[x][y - 1];
}
```

Find nearest biggest:

```
 private long rightWay(int x, int y) {
    List<Long> pickList = new ArrayList<>();
    long up = moveUp(x, y);
    long right = moveRight(x, y);
    long down = moveDown(x, y);
    long left = moveLeft(x, y);
    if (up != -1 && up < map[x][y]) {
        pickList.add(moveUp(x, y));
    }
    if (right != -1 && right < map[x][y]) {
        pickList.add(moveRight(x, y));
    }
    if (down != -1 && down < map[x][y]) {
        pickList.add(moveDown(x, y));
    }
    if (left != -1 && left < map[x][y]) {
        pickList.add(moveLeft(x, y));
    }
    if (pickList.size() == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        Collections.sort(pickList);
        for (int i = 0; i < pickList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("right way " + i + " -> " + pickList.get(i));
        }
        return pickList.get(pickList.size() - 1);
    }

}
```

Then find the longest way using only nearest biggest values:

```
private void findRoute(long[][] route, long current, int width, int height) {
    System.out.println("width = " + width + " height = " + height);
    long nextSpetHeight = rightWay(width, height);
    System.out.println("max = " + nextSpetHeight);
    if (nextSpetHeight == -1) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (nextSpetHeight == moveUp(width, height)) {
            findRoute(route, nextSpetHeight, width - 1, height);
            way.add(nextSpetHeight);
        }
        if (nextSpetHeight == moveRight(width, height)) {
            findRoute(route, nextSpetHeight, width, height + 1);
            way.add(nextSpetHeight);
        }
        if (nextSpetHeight == moveDown(width, height)) {
            findRoute(route, nextSpetHeight, width + 1, height);
            way.add(nextSpetHeight);
        }
        if (nextSpetHeight == moveLeft(width, height)) {
            findRoute(route, nextSpetHeight, width, height - 1);
            way.add(nextSpetHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

And the size of `way` would be the length  of such  route.
But now I don't  know **how to find all possible routes from some coordinates to find the longest of them**. I mean I don't know what it is a best way to come back on "fork" and continue with another route.

I hope the explanation is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying (or not) that you are not allowed to move from a smaller to a bigger number? Does the route have to go 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 98, and so forth, or may it go 100, 79, 6, 43, 87, …? Is distance measured in number of squares only, or by, say, the sum of the numbers you pass?

Comment: @OleV.V. you can move only from bigger to smaller. So you can't move between equal numbers.

Comment: So the route can never be longer than 99 steps.

Comment: I have deleted my previous comments on the computational complexity of the task. The answer posted by David Pérez Cabrera proves that my reasoning was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see this problem like a directed graph problem, you can apply the known graphs algorithm.

This is an implementation of [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm)

At the first time, It search the local-max values on points matrix. They'll be the first candidates, then the algorithm iterates over candidates, It follows the Johnson's algorithm. And It computes all lengths to any point.

```
public class Solver {

    private static class Point {
        int x;
        int y;

        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    private static class State {

        static State best;
        State parent;
        List<State> children = new ArrayList<>();
        int length;
        Point p;

        public State(State parent, Point p) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.p = p;
            this.length = parent.length + 1;
            this.parent.children.add(this);
            if (best.length < length) {
                best = this;
            }
        }

        public State(Point p) {
            this.parent = null;
            this.p = p;
            this.length = 1;
            if (best == null) {
                best = this;
            }
        }

        public void checkParent(State st) {
            if (st.length + 1 > length) {
                parent.children.remove(this);
                this.parent = st;
                updateLength();
            }
        }

        private void updateLength() {
            this.length = parent.length + 1;
            if (best.length < length) {
                best = this;
            }
            for (State state : children) {
                state.updateLength();
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkRange(int min, int max, int x) {
        return min <= x && x < max;
    }

    public static boolean maxLocal(int x, int y, int[][] points) {
        int value = points[x][y];
        if (x > 0 && points[x - 1][y] > value) {
            return false;
        }
        if (y > 0 && points[x][y - 1] > value) {
            return false;
        }
        if (x < points.length - 1 && points[x + 1][y] > value) {
            return false;
        }
        return !(y < points[0].length - 1 && points[x][y + 1] > value);
    }

    private static List<Point> getNeigbours(int x, int y, int[][] points) {
        int value = points[x][y];
        List<Point> result = new ArrayList<>(4);
        if (x > 0 && points[x - 1][y] < value) {
            result.add(new Point(x - 1, y));
        }
        if (y > 0 && points[x][y - 1] < value) {
            result.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
        }
        if (x < points.length - 1 && points[x + 1][y] < value) {
            result.add(new Point(x + 1, y));
        }
        if (y < points[0].length - 1 && points[x][y + 1] < value) {
            result.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int[][] generateRandomPoint(int width, int height, int max) {
        int[][] result = new int[width][height];
        Random rand = new Random(0L);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
                result[i][j] = rand.nextInt(max);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] points = generateRandomPoint(50, 50, 100);
        State[][] states = new State[points.length][points[0].length];
        List<State> candidates = new ArrayList<>(points.length*points[0].length);
        for (int x = 0; x < points.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < points[0].length; y++) {
                if (maxLocal(x, y, points)) {
                    states[x][y] = new State(new Point(x, y));
                    candidates.add(states[x][y]);
                }
            }
        }
        while (!candidates.isEmpty()) {
            State candidate = candidates.remove(candidates.size() - 1);
            for (Point p : getNeigbours(candidate.p.x, candidate.p.y, points)) {
                if (states[p.x][p.y] == null) {
                    states[p.x][p.y] = new State(candidate, p);
                    candidates.add(states[p.x][p.y]);
                } else {
                    states[p.x][p.y].checkParent(candidate);
                }
            }
        }
        State temp = State.best;
        List<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<>(temp.length);
        while (temp != null) {
            pointList.add(temp.p);
            temp = temp.parent;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < points.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < points[0].length; y++) {
                if (points[x][y] < 10) {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                } else if (points[x][y] < 100) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(points[x][y] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("-------");
        for (Point point : pointList) {
            System.out.println(point.x + ", " + point.y + " -> " + points[point.x][point.y]);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("lengths:");
        for (int x = 0; x < points.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < points[0].length; y++) {
                if (states[x][y].length < 10) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(states[x][y].length + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It prints (with 10 x 10 matrix)

- First block: The 2D-matrix (10x10)
- Second block: The coordinates of the longest solution from min to max values.
- Last block: The Coordinate's length.

output:

```
 60  48  29  47  15  53  91  61  19  54 
 77  77  73  62  95  44  84  75  41  20 
 43  88  24  47  52  60   3  82  92  23 
 45  45  37  87   2  62  25  53  38  35 
 60  75  55  30  98  91  74  36  12  62 
 19  77  16  46   7  16   8  37  43  47 
 87  88   5  58   8  17  51  18  58  18 
 38  72  57  51  26  80  97  62  35  20 
 67  73  17  69   5  52  89  43   1  41 
 23  80  68  14  16  23  57  22   5  71 
-------
5, 4 -> 7
6, 4 -> 8
7, 4 -> 26
7, 3 -> 51
7, 2 -> 57
7, 1 -> 72
8, 1 -> 73
9, 1 -> 80

lengths:
 2  3  6  5  6  2  1  4  5  1 
 1  2  3  4  1  5  2  3  4  5 
 6  1  7  6  5  4  5  2  1  4 
 5  4  5  1  6  3  4  3  4  3 
 4  3  4  5  1  2  3  5  5  1 
 5  2  5  2  8  4  5  4  3  2 
 2  1  5  1  7  3  2  4  1  5 
 4  3  4  5  6  2  1  2  3  4 
 3  2  5  1  7  3  2  3  4  2 
 4  1  2  6  5  4  3  4  5  1
```

Comment: Ok. But how to log out the longest one?

Comment: @PeterParker this is logging out the longest one!